# System of Equations involving complex lying on unit circle

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations, alternative-proof

We are looking for an alternative proof for the following system of equations:

$t$ and $s$ are two complex numbers  and $\phi$ a real number such that
$$\Sigma:\,\begin{cases}
t^2+s^2=1\\
(s+it)^n+(s-it)^n=2\cos(\phi)
\end{cases}
$$
Here’s one approach:

Since $s^2+t^2=1$, $ s+it$ and $s-it$ are conjugate therefore there is $\alpha$ so that $s+it=e^{i\alpha}$ and $s-it=e^{-i\alpha}$

Edit:( $\color\red{\text{this last point is false as pointed by Marty Cohen}})$.

(Btw it should be a way of proving that: if $\Sigma$ holds then $s$
and $t$ are real numbers.)

Thus $\Sigma$ is equivalent to: $\cos{(n\alpha)}=\cos\phi$ which, modulo $2\pi$ provides two solutions: $\alpha=\dfrac{\phi}{n}$ and $\alpha=-\dfrac{\phi}{n}$.

Finally: $$\Sigma\iff
\begin{cases} 
s+it=\exp\left(\dfrac{\phi}n\right)\\
s-it =\exp\left(-\dfrac{\phi}n\right)
\end{cases}
\textbf{ or } 
\begin{cases} 
s+it=\exp\left(-\dfrac{\phi}n\right)\\
s-it =\exp\left(\dfrac{\phi}n\right)
\end{cases}
$$
Which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You say that
$s$ and $t$ 
are complex numbers,
not just real numbers.

If $s = a+ib, t = c+id$,
then
$s+it
=a+ib+i(c+id)
=a-d+i(b+c)
$
and
$s-it
=a+ib-i(c+id)
=a+d+i(b-c)
$
so they are not conjugate.

However
$s^2+t^2
=(a+ib)^2+(c+id)^2
=a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2+2i(ab+cd)
$
and if this $=1$
then
$a^2-b^2+c^2-d^2
=1
$
and
$ab+cd = 0$.

Going a little further

$\begin{array}\\
r_n
&=(s+it)^n+(s-it)^n\\
&=(a-d+i(b+c))^n+(a+d+i(b-c))^n\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}i^{n-k}((a-d)^k(b+c)^{n-k}+(a+d)^k(b-c)^{n-k})\\
\text{so}\\
r_{2n-1}
&=(s+it)^{2n-1}+(s-it)^{2n-1}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{2n-1} \binom{2n-1}{k}i^{2n-1-k}((a-d)^k(b+c)^{2n-1-k}+(a+d)^k(b-c)^{2n-1-k})\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\binom{2n-1}{2k}i^{2n-1-2k}((a-d)^{2k}(b+c)^{2n-1-2k}+(a+d)^{2k}(b-c)^{2n-1-2k})+\binom{2n-1}{2k+1}i^{2n-1-2k-1}((a-d)^{2k+1}(b+c)^{2n-1-2k-1}+(a+d)^{2k+1}(b-c)^{2n-1-2k-1})\right)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(\binom{2n-1}{2k}(-i)(-1)^{n-k}((a-d)^{2k}(b+c)^{2n-1-2k}+(a+d)^{2k}(b-c)^{2n-1-2k})+\binom{2n-1}{2k+1}(-1)^{n-k-1}((a-d)^{2k+1}(b+c)^{2n-1-2k-1}+(a+d)^{2k+1}(b-c)^{2n-1-2k-1})\right)\\
&=(-i)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \binom{2n-1}{2k}(-1)^{n-k}((a-d)^{2k}(b+c)^{2n-1-2k}+(a+d)^{2k}(b-c)^{2n-1-2k})\\
&+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{2n-1}{2k+1}(-1)^{n-k-1}((a-d)^{2k+1}(b+c)^{2n-1-2k-1}+(a+d)^{2k+1}(b-c)^{2n-1-2k-1})\\
\end{array}
$

And that's enough for now.

Comment: I see the point. Btw I think that should be easier to prove that it $\Sigma$ holds then $s$ and $t$ are real. Your approach leads to unpleasant calculus